# Python joining strings fails

Tags: python, string, join

I have an odd problem with my code and cannot find the mistake.

I am trying the reverse names in "SURNAME, First Names, Religious Title" format to "First Names Surname" and have written the following lines of code:

```
    try:
      for x in range(0, df_length):
          print(df_length - x)
          e_df=df.iloc[[x]].fillna("@") # virtual value to avoid issues with empty data frames

          # CLEAN PERSON NAMES

          pers_name=e_df['pers_name'].values[0]
          print(pers_name)
          if "," in pers_name:
            pers_new=pers_name.split(",")
            first_name=pers_new[1].strip()
            print(first_name)
            last_name=pers_new[0].title().strip() # change "all caps" to sentence case
            print(last_name)
            rel_title=pers_new[2].strip()
            name_list=(first_name, last_name)

            try:
              name_reversed=" ".join(name_list) # religious titles are being ignored
              print("This is the new name: ", name_reversed)
            except Exception as e:
              print(e)
          else:
            name_reversed=re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", pers_name)
          print(name_reversed)
          person_cleaned.append(name_reversed)
    
    except IndexError:
      print("No more names found.")

    # add column with cleaned person names

    print(person_cleaned)
    print(len(person_cleaned))
    df['pers_cleaned']=person_cleaned

    frame_list.append(df)
```

The input data look like this:

| factoid_ID | pers_ID | pers_name | alternative_name | additional_info | source | event_type | place_name | pers_title | pers_function | event_date | date_before_date | event_after_date | inst_name | rel_pers | source_quotations | comment | info_dump | source_site |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5637 | OCR | DORSCH, Anton Joseph |  | am 16.1.1798 traf er in Aachen ein und wurde Direktorialkommissar für das Roer-Departement | Praetorius, Professoren, S.139; Hans-Joachim Philipp, Anton Joseph Dorsch. Materialsammlung, -Manuskript im Universitätsarchiv Mainz-; Helmut Mathy, Anton Joseph Dorsch, 1758-1819, in: Mainzer Zeitschrift 62, 1967, S. 1-55 hier: * 13.6.1758; R. Schmitt, S. 56 Anm.101 hier: * 13.6.1758; RPh 294v, 296v,321r,321v, 322r,322v; Prot. phil. Fak. , S.109; Prot, theol. Fak.1779, Bl.81b; 1780, B1.83a; RTh 68v, 71r; Hansen I, S.48 Nr.44 hier: * 13.6.1758; NDB 4, S.85 f.) | Funktionsausübung | Aachen |  | Direktor |  |  | 1798-01-16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5638 | OCR | DORSCH, Anton Joseph |  | 1799 wurde er Mitglied der Freimaurer-Johannisloge in Aachen | Praetorius, Professoren, S.139; Hans-Joachim Philipp, Anton Joseph Dorsch. Materialsammlung, -Manuskript im Universitätsarchiv Mainz-; Helmut Mathy, Anton Joseph Dorsch, 1758-1819, in: Mainzer Zeitschrift 62, 1967, S. 1-55 hier: * 13.6.1758; R. Schmitt, S. 56 Anm.101 hier: * 13.6.1758; RPh 294v, 296v,321r,321v, 322r,322v; Prot. phil. Fak. , S.109; Prot, theol. Fak.1779, Bl.81b; 1780, B1.83a; RTh 68v, 71r; Hansen I, S.48 Nr.44 hier: * 13.6.1758; NDB 4, S.85 f.) | Funktionsausübung | Aachen |  | Mitglied | 1799 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2006 | OCR | SCHEUICHAVIUS (Schevichavius), Gisbert, SJ | im Sommer 1600 ging er nach Aachen und im November 1600 nach Graz als Rektor des Jesuitenkollegs | Nom. rev., S.8; Cat. Jes. 1597, S.l; De Back.-Som. VII, Sp.776; Duhr I, S. 417; Duhr 11,1, S. 337 Anm. 1; Verzeichnis theol. Fak., S.l) | Amtsantritt | Aachen, Graz |  | Rektor | 1600 |  |  | Jesuitenkolleg Erfurt, Jesuiten ### |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The output I get is this:

```
7155
 DORSCH, Anton Joseph
Anton Joseph
Dorsch
No more names found.
[]
```

So I can successfully extract the name components I need and convert the all caps string in the surname to sentence case, but merging the strings to form a new name fails. And then the whole script breaks before moving on to the next name. Did I use the `join()` function in a wrong (deprecated?) manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is failing in your code is this specific line:

```
rel_title=pers_new[2].strip()
```

The length of the `pers_new` is 2, in your example, you would have:

```
['DORSCH', ' Anton Joseph']
```

so when you write `pers_new[2]` gives IndexError exception. The code is not reaching the `join()`.

I guess you forgot to remove that line. Because you are not using anywhere the `rel_title` variable.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. Struck with blindness!